# AgGrid custom filter not created until interaction

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a custom filter component on a column in my grid. I've noticed that the filter component is not constructed until I click on the filter icon in the column header. This means that the data is not filtered according to my default settings (e.g., filter out records where `status == StatusEnum.Complete`).

As a workaround, I've found that I can get a filter instance in the `onGridReady` event by calling `api.getFilterInstance('status')`, and this causes the filter component to be created and thereby apply default filtering.

This workaround seems a bit clunky. The `filter` variable is unused in the `onGridReady` event, which causes warnings in the IDE / build. Another developer may come along and delete this line of code, thinking it is unnecessary.

Is there a better way to force my custom filter to be instantiated when the grid is created? I'm using AgGrid 17.1 and Angular 4.4.

The grid is configured like so:

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    enableFilter: true,
    onGridReady: (event) => {
        let filter = event.api.getFilterInstance("status"); // forces the filter component to be constructed
        let data = this.loadAsyncData();
        event.api.setRowData(data);
    },
    columnDefs: [
    ...
    {
        headerName: "Status",
        field: "status",
        filterFramework: MyCustomStatusFilterComponent,
        filterParams: {
            valueGetter: (obj) => { return obj.data.statusEnum; },
            hideCompleteByDefault: true,
            ...
        }
    },
    ....
    ]
}
```

I've set up an [example that demonstrates the issue](https://plnkr.co/edit/M9Zjz91Seys9JgWWJRX6?p=preview). Note the "hack" on line 63 of `app.component.ts`.

Comment: I'm sort of interested in looking at this, but you don't have a test case, which makes it difficult to help you. Can you set up a demo showing the problem? You can start [from this](https://plnkr.co/edit/oZ5hOkDw11nONZVNoLOo?p=preview) or any other example from the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/documentation-main/documentation.php).

Comment: @thirtydot plunkr added. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all - it's two independent thing, custom filter and filter initialization.

I suppose you've mixed those two phases and trying to achieve an unexpected result.

Your custom filter shouldn't contain pre-defined logic **cuz `init` will occur only with first touch of your filter**, you have to divide your logic and then in `onGridReady` you can execute `setModel` with needed things. 
or keep a hack as you've already mentioned

Comment: This approach looks like it will work for me. I'm still curious, though, why the filters are not initialized until they are first touched. Is this somewhere in the `ag-grid` documentation?

Comment: @djs: I can't see it explicitly in the docs, but it doesn't matter. If you look in the source, it's "initialise on demand", and it's almost certainly for performance reasons. Look at the very first feature they list: https://www.ag-grid.com/features-overview/ ("Outstanding Performance"). Think about it: the set filter has to go through every one of your [(set it to: 100,000) rows](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) to collect the unique values. If you have 22+ columns of this, the grid will lag on startup (especially on slow hardware).

Answer (score 0):

Here You Use Custom Filtering,

If Your Row Not Bind with Value Then You Use Custom Filtering.

```
         {
            headerName: "Date",
            field: "date",

            //Custom  Filter Start

            filterValueGetter: (params: ICellRendererParams) => 
            {
              if (this.transactionIsEmpty(params.data)) 
              {
                const tx: Transaction = params.data;
                return moment(tx.date).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
              }
            },

            //Custom  Filter End

            cellStyle: { 'text-align': 'left' },
            minWidth: 250,
        }
```